# Angular 2 - How do I write a Http get promise in my header?

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular 2 - How do I write a Http get promise?

I'm importing http and want to set the http header with my auth token.
Then I want to write a http get and put the response into a promise to return to the method that calls it.

**So far I have this:**

```
 import {Http, Headers} from "angular2/http";
 import {EnvironmentService} from './environmentService';

 export class AuthService {
     private environmentService: EnvironmentService;
     private http: Http;
     private header: Headers;

     contructor(_environmentService: EnvironmentService, _http: Http, _header: Headers){
         this.environmentService = _environmentService;
         this.http = _http;

         this.header.append('Authorization', '1234');  
         this.header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');      
     }

     getSpotifyData = ():Promise<Object> => {
         return this.http
           .get('http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=foo',             {headers:this.header})
           .map((response) => {
             return response.json()
           })
           .toPromise();
     }

 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show Code for better understanding

Comment: Code just added above

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass [`headers`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.45/modules/angular2/src/http/interfaces.ts#L33) into the second argument of [`http.get`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.45/modules/angular2/src/http/http.ts#L116) method and you can use [`.toPromise`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/v4.0.6/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md) method to convert an `Observable` into a `Promise`.

```ts
export class AuthService {
  // ...

  testApiCall(): any {
    return this.http
      .get('http://localhost:3333/api/', { 
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'BearerTokenGoesHear'
        }
      })
      .map((response) => {
        // some response manipulation
        return response.json()
      })
      .toPromise();
  }
}
```

Take a look at [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/WulgR3hNvaztjzDpDrPf?p=preview).

Comment: Hi, I've done what you've said and I get type script compiler errors.
I have updated my code at the top to show you where I'm currently at. Thank you

Comment: I don't know what the errors you have. Try to change return type of `testApiCall` to the `any`. Maybe it'll help.