# I can't access object property of a promise

Tags: angular, ionic3, es6-promise

I am creating an ionic 3 app using promises. In my provider I have this promise:

```
getUserCountryCode() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get<ClientData>("https://ipinfo.io/json").subscribe(data => {
        let country = {
             code: data.country,
             city: data.city,
             ip:   data.ip
        }
        resolve(data.country);

      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
```

and in my header.ts module I have this code to consume the promise:

```
 getCountryCode() {
   return  this.clientDataProfile.getUserCountryCode()
     .then(data => {

     return data.country; 
       //error Property country does not exist on type {}

    });
  }
```

I just can't get the types concept right. I with and without the :

```
interface ClientData {
  city: string,
  country: string,
  ip: string
}
```

I only need the country property....but the above error on any properties of data.....I know I am missing something very basic here can someone shed some light on this.....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface isn't the problem here. The issue is that you are resolving `data.country` in 
`getUserCountryCode` which returns a string

```
// the argument provided to resolve becomes data in getCountryCode
// as data.country is a string, you don't need to return data.country
// in getCountryCode
resolve(data.country);
```

So in your header.ts file you need to change your function to just return `data` as `data` is just a 
string because you just resolved the promise in `getUserCountryCode` function with `data.country` which 
in turn becomes your `data` in `getCountryCode` function.

```
getCountryCode(): string {
    // data here is a string. It contains country code
    return  this.clientDataProfile.getUserCountryCode()
        .then((data: string) => data);
}
```

In your `getUserCountryCode` function you could just use `toPromise` 
[like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33649961/4512411) instead of using `subscribe`
inside a promise.

Comment: Thanks @dhyey .....I did miss this particular ES6 assignment of the resolved value. I am still not clear why .then (data=>{ return (data)}) doesn't work. Am I not passing a string into the function and returning the same value.....seems silly to do it now..... but why does it assign type {} to data. I thought it would inferred that data was a string from the promise resolved type?

Answer (score 0):

In the `getUserCountryCode()` function the data you are resolving the`country` object. Therefore in the callback of `getCountryCode` statement you will get the country object. Instead of using `data.country` use only `data`, as `data` is the object of type `country`.

Also I dont think returning the data from the callback in `getCountryCode` make any sense. Because `clientDataProfile.getUserCountryCode` returns a promise which is async operation. Here you will have to do something else to handle this scenario.

```
 getCountryCode() {
    return this.clientDataProfile.getUserCountryCode().then(country => {
         console.log(country); 
    });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think you are on the same track as Amal. I actually had the code you have in your answer but it produced an object when I wanted a string....see my comments above.

Answer (score -1):

Change your return definition for the getCountryCode inside the service

```
getUserCountryCode() : ClientData {

}
```

Comment: OP is resolving `data.country` in `getUserCountryCode` which is string according to interface